# Access Isotope data from instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Looking for a basic response that I can use to help aid my understanding of the Javascript / jQuery plugin Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

I am trying to access the current number of filtered items from the instance and am having some syntax trouble, I believe.

My code thus far:

```
$('#menu select').change(function(){
    var $filtered = $('.content').data('isotope').$filteredAtoms;
    $('#numresources').replaceWith( $filtered.length );
});
```

Which returns an error from the console that the $filtered object isn't defined.

Happy to post a fiddle (or use the new-fangled code snippet thing) if more context is needed. Thanks in advance!
-- Steve

Comment: A jsfiddle will help solve your issue.

Comment: What is $filteredAtoms? If you are just getting the class names the first part of that should be on the right track, you'll just need to actually call the class name in a jQuery selector.